# Inserting large table with duplicates into new table with unique key with mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with about 2.5 million rows, Table1, that has duplicates.
I created a new table, Table2, with the same column names, but with a unique index for the columns I want.

I want to insert the data from Table1 into Table2, removing duplicates on the way. I use this query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
```

Problem is, half an hour run time isn't enough for this process to go through. Any recommendations as to how to achieve this? Is there a simple way to transfer the data by chunks, even though there isn't an index in Table1 that's linearly ordered?

Comment: Why is half an hour relevant?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's just the maximum I've tried so far and it seems rather long, no?

Comment: Did you look at the rows that were created? If they look correct, then just let it run. Afterall you only going to run this once

Comment: Rows appear only after the whole query finishes. If it is aborted before end, no rows are inserted (even if you don't use transactions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try inserting several time with loads of 1000 rows, the first query will give you an idea how much time it takes but time spent by each query might increase

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 limit 1000;
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 limit 1000;
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 limit 1000;
[...]
```

if second query doesn't insert anything (not sure if ignore statement is applied before or after limit), you would have to use offsets:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 limit 1000;
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 limit 1000 offset 1000;
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 limit 1000 offset 2000;
[...]
```

if it is still too slow, you can try adding an outer join to avoid trying inserting data already inserted, but might required for performance that both tables are indexed (primary index not required).

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table2 SELECT TABLE1.* FROM TABLE1 left outer join Table2 on Table1.pk_column=Table2.pk_column where Table2.pk_column is null limit 1000;
[...]
```

If it is still too slow, write a stored procedure that loops on initial table.

Comment: the limit clause helped me; only around 2 million did I need to limit the offset to 100,000. Up until then 500,000 worked fast enough.

Comment: you can use the limit you want, most of the time, number of rows inserted per second increases when you choose a higher limit, sometimes not, another problem is that long queries might create trouble if you've got concurrent transactions or replication.  If your  problem is solved, please put that your acccept the answer.